# Automate saving a PDF version of a vsdx file in a SharePoint Doc Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, flow, visio

I have an issue that only one-third of my team have Visio installed, as we are the ones doing the process mapping. The other 2/3 however still use and analyse our maps.

It is a real pain to have to manually save a PDF version of the vsdx file, each time we make changes. We are using a standard SharePoint Doc Libary as the repository.

Has anyone come across a way this can be automated through Flow or SPD? Looking for a no (low)-code fix for two reasons. I don't know how to do custom coding and neither does anyone else, if it required changing.

Based on my google searching, the answer is no, but I won't believe that until someone here confirms it.

Cheers

Scott

Comment: [Muhimbi PDF][1] provide service for PDF converting, a free 30 day trial is available of this service. https://flow.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/convert-files-using-muhimbi/